# Linux VM installation on MacBook Pro with macOS Sierra 10.12

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, unix

Using MacBook 13" Retina display with macOS Sierra 10.12.

I already have Boot Camp option along with Windows.

Will it be possible for me to use VM on the same machine for Linux?

Comment: Do you have enough Ram and disk space to do That?
Parallels, VMware, and Virtualbox are available for doing that.

Comment: Yes @LexS I have enough memory to install I have 256GB, 8 GB RAM, machine is almost new, no much space is used.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) (free), but any works. Some other virtualization software are [VMware Fusion for Mac](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion.html) (paid), [Parallels Desktop
for Mac](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/) (paid), QEMU (free, bit more complicated install process, see below). Just make sure you have enough RAM, CPU power, and disk space.

Links for how to install QEMU: [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-install-QEMU-on-a-Mac) (easiest process), [The Intobooks](https://theintobooks.wordpress.com/2016/03/03/installing-qemu-on-mac-os-x-el-capitan/), [Official QEMU instructions for Mac hosts](http://wiki.qemu.org/Hosts/Mac), and [Installing QEMU on OS X](https://github.com/psema4/pine/wiki/Installing-QEMU-on-OS-X).

Comment: As for Qemu links: Quora `No answers yet` and all other links are not that really helpful :/